# How to overload a server using j meter

Tags: server, jmeter, load-balancing

I'm trying to test max no of users that my website can manage and at what number of users will server go down.

I have used j meter but couldn't overload or slow down website. I only sent GET request to 3 of my pages using multiple threads.

Is there any other method to overload my server ?

waiting for reply.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can really slow down the backend is by simulating a load that stresses the backend systems.

What I mean is say your server can handle 2000 requests per second and you only send 20 requests per second via jmeter, your systems wont be under stress and your website will work as usual. In this case you need to send 2000 RPS hits on your server from the load generator machine.

The idea is to understand this practical limit of the server. To do that start with a relative small load of 10 TPS and run the test for 15 minutes. After that keep on increasing the load by a factor of 10 till you reach this limit. I am sure once you reach this limit, your website will be very slow to respond because it will be under tremendous stress.

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least 4 reasons for you not being able to stress your website:

1. The website simply cannot be stressed as it is being deployed on [elastic scalable instance](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) in the cloud so it scales up when the load increases and scales down when the load gets back to normal or stops. If this is the case - you will need to check the scaling factor, i.e. when you increase the load 2x times the throughput should increase ideally in 2x times as well (refer your [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) or [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) for exact number)
2. You don't use the website the way which real users will use it. If you send 3 GET requests to static URLs only the website (or underlying web or application server) could [cache it](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/ehandbook/Server-side-caching-defined-and-clarified) so the server doesn't parse the request and generate the response, it simply returns the page from memory which is very cheap and quick operation
3. You're not sending enough requests or not having enough test iterations/duration. It might be the case some threads have already done their work and some even haven't been yet started. Ensure that you really produce the load you expect to conduct by looking into [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) charts.
4. Basically the same as point 3, but for the different reason. You might fail to conduct the required load because JMeter default configuration is suitable for tests development and/or debugging, however when it comes to real load testing you need to perform some extra steps the mandatory ones are:

   - Run your test in non-GUI mode
   - Disable all the listeners

Check out [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for a piece of advice on getting the most of your JMeter installation. Also be aware that if you cannot reach target number of users or throughput using single JMeter instance you can run JMeter in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when several machines will be executing the same tests at the same time.